# Twilio SMS to Voice Call

Tags: twilio, sms

Brand new to Twilio, is there a way through Twilio Studio to initiate a voice call from an SMS trigger?  I've searched extensively for this and cannot find an answer.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the Make Outgoing Call Widget as part of your Studio flow. This will call the SMS participant on the phone and connect them to your Studio Flow.

[Make Outgoing Call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/make-outgoing-call)